# Centos - Root access with key, force to ask password too

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, root

I have a CentOS server in AWS Amazon. They gave me a key, but since its in my computer, I would like to make the server ask for a password too.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSH which CentOS uses doesn't support requiring both a key and password as far as I know. What you can do however is to password protect the key stored on your local computer.

Easiest way is probably to generate a new key using `ssh-keygen` and then install it into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server. `ssh-keygen` will ask you to set a passphrase.

You can also encrypt it using `openssl`, but it depends on the key format so need more info for that.

Disclaimer: I'm not too familiar with AWS so don't know where the key you have came from.